# Firestore type mismatch : The argument type 'List<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<JobPost>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In a flutter project, I am trying to make a `CollectionGroup` query. But messed up with types. Here is my code :

```
Stream<Either<JobPostFailure, List<JobPost>>> watchAppliedJobPosts({
    required String seamanId,
  }) async* {
    yield* _firestore
        .collectionGroup(ConstStrings.applications)
        .where(ConstStrings.seamanId, isEqualTo: seamanId)
        .snapshots()
        .map((querySnapshot) {
      return right(querySnapshot.docs.map((docSnapshot) {
        final jobPostDocRef = docSnapshot.reference;
        jobPostDocRef.snapshots().map((doc) {
          final jobPost = JobPostDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain();
          return jobPost;
        });
      }).toList());
    });
  }
```

I expect to get a `List<JobPost>`, but getting following error at this line `return right(querySnapshot.docs.map((docSnapshot) {...`:

> The argument type 'List<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'List<JobPost>'.

Though I am returning `List<JobPost>`, error says it is `List<Null>`. Where is the error? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` keyword:

```
return /* <-- */ jobPostDocRef.snapshots().map((doc) {
```

That said, why are you complicating this function with an `Either` return type, when there clearly is no other option in your method? It always returns `right`, so you might as well just remove the `Either` from the return type.

Comment: Using that return now the error is : `The argument type 'List<Stream<JobPost>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<JobPost>'.`

Comment: Using `Either` type because later I'll handle propable exceptions.

Comment: Your `.toList())` call is one line to far. It needs to be one line higher up in your code.

Comment: Now the error : `The argument type 'Iterable<Future<List<JobPost>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<JobPost>'`.